# Alignment at the center of two multicolumn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I would center 10e-1 and 10e-3 at the center of the 4 multicolumn. How can I do?

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]}
        \toprule
            {\emph{Nodi}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PEP} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                        & \num{10e-1} &     &       & \num{10e-3} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                        & {BC}   & {PNC}    & {BC} & {PNC} \\
        \midrule
        1               & 1.1107 & 1.1112  & 1.001  & 1.001 \\
        3               & 1.3046 & 1.1488  & 1.003  & 1.0029 \\
        7               & 1.597  & 1.1734  & 1.007  & 1.006 \\
        12              & 1.8435 & 1.188   & 1.0117 & 1.0089 \\
        20              & 2.0836 & 1.2009  & 1.0201 & 1.0122 \\
        25              & 2.1777 & 1.2064  & 1.0246 & 1.0134 \\
        35              & 2.3101 & 1.2141  & 1.0347 & 1.0153 \\
        50              & 2.4443 & 1.2223  & 1.0488 & 1.0167 \\
        65              & 2.5501 & 1.228   & 1.0636 & 1.0175 \\
        75              & 2.6109 & 1.2308  & 1.0723 & 1.0178 \\
        90              & 2.6915 & 1.235   & 1.0864 & 1.0184 \\
        100             & 2.7417 & 1.237   & 1.0954 & 1.0186 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please, add the necessary packages that are needed for typesetting the example. Did you try `{\num{10e-1}}`? It seems to be all that's needed.

Comment: Is `& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\num{10e-1}\quad\num{10e-3}}  \\ ` what you are looking for? Does not quite make sense to me, but that does place both the `10e-1` and `10e-3` at the center of the 4 columns.

Comment: @PeterGrill yeah right...now it works great....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the two elements centered within the four columns, simply treat them as  one `\multicolumn` element:

```
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\num{10e-1}\quad\num{10e-3}} \\
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]
                     S[table-format=1.4]}
        \toprule
            {\emph{Nodi}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PEP} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\num{10e-1}\quad\num{10e-3}}  \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                        & {BC}   & {PNC}    & {BC} & {PNC} \\
        \midrule
        1               & 1.1107 & 1.1112  & 1.001  & 1.001 \\
        3               & 1.3046 & 1.1488  & 1.003  & 1.0029 \\
        7               & 1.597  & 1.1734  & 1.007  & 1.006 \\
        12              & 1.8435 & 1.188   & 1.0117 & 1.0089 \\
        20              & 2.0836 & 1.2009  & 1.0201 & 1.0122 \\
        25              & 2.1777 & 1.2064  & 1.0246 & 1.0134 \\
        35              & 2.3101 & 1.2141  & 1.0347 & 1.0153 \\
        50              & 2.4443 & 1.2223  & 1.0488 & 1.0167 \\
        65              & 2.5501 & 1.228   & 1.0636 & 1.0175 \\
        75              & 2.6109 & 1.2308  & 1.0723 & 1.0178 \\
        90              & 2.6915 & 1.235   & 1.0864 & 1.0184 \\
        100             & 2.7417 & 1.237   & 1.0954 & 1.0186 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```